# Bootstrap component in injectable service

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular2-services

In our ASP.NET Core app, we dynamically load some HTML partial views with Ajax to not refreshing the page. In these views we add Angular 2 component, so when we display our partial view we need to bootstrap the component : that's what we do in a injectable service.

The partial view :

```
<home></home>
```

The service :

```
@Injectable()
export class ComponentService {
    constructor() { }

    loadComponent(path: string): void {
        System
            .config({
                packages: {
                    app: {
                        defaultExtension: 'js',
                    }
                }
        });

        System
            .import('app/home/home.component')
            .then((component) => {
                console.log("Import done !");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error.bind(console);
            });
    }
}
```

NB : The exact same code directly inserted in the partial view works the first time, and after that I have an error : "angular2.dev.js:23941 EXCEPTION: Expected to not be in Angular Zone, but it is!".

I see in the console that there is no errors (in my service) because I see "Import done !" and `component` object is loaded, but not bootstraped.

The component :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: 'home.component.html'
})
export class Home {
    // Some logic    
}

bootstrap(Home,
    [
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        HomeService
    ]);
```

Any ideas ? The big idea behind this is : how to load one Angular 2 component multiple time ?

Answer (score 2):

In fact you can bootstrap several times but not the same component. It's a restriction of Angular2

That said, I would also define once the configuration of SystemJS.

I don't know what is actually you use case, Angular2 provides a way to dynamically load components inside other components (for example, the bootstrapped one) using the `DynamicComponentLoader` one.

See this link for more details:

- `https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html

Comment: Thanks ! `DynamicComponentLoader` is not exactly what I'm searching. `<home></home>` is already here, all I need is to launch my component and inject the template HTML into the DOM, multiple time if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**update**

`.dispose()` is `destroy()` **since beta.16**

**original**

Not sure what you mean by "first time, and after that"

You might need to dispose the component before you bootstrap it again

```
bootstrap(Home,
    [
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        HomeService
    ]).then((ref => {
      xxx = ref; // store ref
    });
```

Destroy the component

```
xxx.dispose();
```

Then you should be able to add it again.